# Is there execute json from wal2json on postgres directly?

Tags: json, postgresql, database-replication, dml, wal

I am new to wal2json. Once the utility produces JSON objects, with the exception of parsing it, etc. Is there a utility (Postgres utility) that can take a query in JSON format and execute it?

Comment: Does the question have any connection to wal2json? If yes, could you explain it?

Comment: The json I get is a product of wal2json. Given its a commonly used tool, looking for a way users of wal2json might have addressed this.

Comment: I see. Unfurtunately, asking for utilities and such is off-topic.